# Facebook pixel through Google Tag Manager from mobile, without a website

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Is it possible to use Facebook/Snapchat pixel (for conversion tracking and retargeting etc) through GTM with events reported only from the mobile app.

I'm currently trying to figure out a way but GTM apparently only supports integrating facebook pixels only for a website. Is there a work around for this?

Could Google Analytics be helpful for conversion tracking?

Comment: Is  there a specific reason you cannot implement Facebook's SDK for their mobile app tracking pixel? Also there is a GTM implementation for mobile apps (which requires that you use Firebase Analytics in your apps: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/).

Comment: I also need to use snapchat pixel as well, so the client side should only be reporting to GTM and it should handle the rest. I'm already using firebase analytics on mobile and I'm receiving my events in GTM and GA as well, I just need to pass those events to facebook...

Comment: @EikePierstorff
A little help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTM for mobile is severely limited comparing to the normal GTM for web.

It is still possible to make a GTM tag that would call a generic function  or send a generic pixel. You can even grab some variables from your firebase user properties and jam into the pixel url. Aaaand it will work! However, it's not as easy as fbq('track'...). You have to know what to send to what endpoint.

Oh, you also will have to ask the app teams to "issue an event" to the GTM listener/function in their code to then be able to use it as a trigger. From our perspective it seems like issuing an event. From the app devs perspective it would look like calling a GTM SDK function and passing a few arguments, one of which would be the event name.

Basically, mobile tracking implementation for third parties goes like so: you have app teams running the GTM SDK function during key conversions, passing appropriate event names. Then you either use those as triggers for simpler third party image requests, or you ask the teams to implement certain SDKs and trigger them directly from those conversion callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the great info.

Can you point me towards an article on how to achieve this and also will this also work on iOS?

Basically what I need is to report events from the mobile and pass em to facebook and snapchat etc via GTM...

Comment: for facebook, you will have to use the API. GTM will likely be pretty useless here, so you will need to ask your app devs for help. Here's the API doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api#send and here is a manual for snapchat: https://businesshelp.snapchat.com/s/article/app-ads-kit?language=en_US I don't think GTM would be handy in either implementation, sadly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I was actually hoping to get it working with only integrating the GTM (Firebase analytics) at the mobile end. Are you suggesting that it's not possible and I have to integrate both facebook and snapchat independently at the mobile side to get it working?

I don't see any point of GTM then? GTM, for my said purpose, only works with web?

Comment: Well, you could try and go further. You could implement tracking for them on web just to analyze the actual payloads and see if you could reproduce the payloads with mobile GTM simple pixel logic. Then try using that as your documentation. It's a rough method, it's unstable in case they update the protocol and the libraries/SDKs, but it could work. But generally yes, if they ask to use their SDK and don't offer manual for GTM tracking, that's a good sign GTM is pretty much useless there. Mobile GTM can only send the simplest pixels with very simple logic in them.